# facebook auto feed does not share image?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

i am auto sharing feeds on my wall in my app, it is working absolutely fine, but when i attach image and link with it, i know image does not appear on localhost, but atleast there comes a success message, but it gives me an error i mentioned in response, any idea?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

                var image_name = '<?=$trx_detail->image_name?>'

                var wallPost = {
                    access_token: '<?php echo $this->facebook->getAccessToken()?>',
                    message: 'test message',
                    link: <? echo "'".CANVAS_URL."'";?>,
                    picture: '<?=base_url()?>path/'+image_name,
                    description: 'test description!'
                };

                FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', wallPost, function(response) {
                    if (!response || response.error) {
                        alert('Error occurred');
                    } else {
                        alert('Success!');
                    }
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found out the problem, sorry for the late answer posting, 
there was an issue with the,

```
 link: <? echo "'".CANVAS_URL."'";?>
```

If you are trying to post images on localhost, the image wil not be displayed then, image will only be displayed on online https server.